# My IOS web photo browser app is using 240mb of real memory .

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am new to ios development. I developed an app which display some images form url. I used MWPhotoBrowser to load my images and cache management. My app is having 33 images to show. I checked the real memory in activity monitor and it started with 15MB and it increased to 240MB by the time when I was seeing my 33rd image. Is this going to be problem if I submit my app to review.

Thanks, 
Priyatham Anisetty

Comment: Whats the maximum number of images you plan on showing? Do you have a limit? Is it the physical image sizes that is increasing memory usage, or is it a leak that is associated with the loading of an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever got your app crash when you test on a real device? If so you certainly need to rethink your memory management.

I remember a training class I have from Lynda.com actually saying at that time, iOS only allow you to use around 50 Mb of the memory, and if any app including app from Apple use more than that, the app will automatically shut down by iOS. I don't know how much memory an app can actually use now but 240 Mb is probably too much since iPhone 4 and iPhone 4S only has 512 Mb in total. I would say if you experience app crash a lot, then you probably will be rejected by Apple.

In general, I think you need to take another look at your memory management and see if you can reuse them and fix the leaks if there is any.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

240MB is simply a huge memory usage and probably indicates a memory leak somewhere in your app. It will probably crash when running for a longer time on an actual device or when you have more images to show. If you're not using ARC make sure all your retains are properly balanced with retains. I recommend you to use the Xcode Analyzer to track down your memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the per answers, any app that uses that much memory will be killed by the operating system. Around 20mb your app will receive warnings, around 35mb iOS will start killing processes and at 50 you're pretty much guaranteed to be long dead. And these could be less if the user has lots of stuff running in the background, as most people do.

1. Post your code if you want specific help. There's lots of things you could potentially be doing wrong
2. Use break points, and the leak analyzer in instrument to try and track down the lines of code that are causing the major memory issues.
3. Obviously, you will need to find a way of only having the images you NEED held in memory. If you're scanning throu many photos, the best way is probably to put them in a table view, since they have a built in reusable identifier property that can dramatically improve your memory footprint.
4. Specifically tell us what method youre using to store your images in memory.